# Empty lists as default parameters - differenece in behaviour

Tags: python, function, default-arguments

If I set an empty list as the default parameter of a function I get a difference in behavior when I add elemets with the append method or when I use the "+" operator. Could someone explain why this happens?

**WITH APPEND**

```
def append_to(n, my_list = []):
    for i in range(n):
        my_list.append(str(i))
    return my_list


a = append_to(5)
print(a)
b = append_to(10)
print(b)
```

**OUT:**

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

**WITH "+"**

```
def append_to(n, my_list = []):
    for i in range(n):
        my_list = my_list + [str(i)]
    return my_list


a = append_to(5)
print(a)
b = append_to(10)
print(b)
```

**OUT:**

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: I think in the second one, ```my_list = my_list + [str(i)]``` creates a new list and over writes the ```my_list``` every time and returns it

Comment: @Sujay is right, your second example creates a new list. You can verify this by replacing `print(a)` with `print(id(a))` and the same with `b`. With `append` they'll have the same `id` and with `+` it will be different.

Comment: @Alex,Sujay - You are right. I checked it with the id method. But why is this so? Because obviously the pitfalls with empty mutable default arguments (e.g.  my_list = []) as mentioned numerous times on stackoverflow do not apply in the second example.

Comment: Your second method will make a shallow copy of both `my_list` and `[str(i)]`. Which means a new list is created that can contain all the elements, but the values contained in the list are references to the original values.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide on shallow vs deep copy](https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/#making-shallow-copies) and the [copy docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: @Alex So in fact with the second method I never modify the original list that always remains at the value []

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.

Comment: @Alex `a = []
print(id(a))
out: 2499142983552
a = a + [1]
print(id(a)) out: 2499143263296`